# split column after first delimiter

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, jet

I need this string to split after the first '-' as follows:

```
DISPLAY VALUE
466500-GO-INF-ITAPPS-EMP-CLERADM

DISPLAY VALUE2
GO-INF-ITAPPS-EMP-CLERADM
```

I've tried substring and charindex with no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `stuff()` is convenient for this:

```
select stuff(value, 1, charindex('-', value), '')
```